# Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker dynamic date (variable)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using  [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)  and creating a form which contains two datepickers.  First one is today's date or the date we can select, the 2nd one is the first one's day plus a week, 7 days.

I am able to have them initially correct.

`$scope.first = new Date();
$scope.second = new Date().setDate( new Date().getDate() + 7);`

However, if I change the first datepicker's date, the 2nd one won't do any changes. I found `{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}` catches the dynamic date. my question is how can I get the first datepickers's date to be a variable and manipulate in my .js file?  then I can add +7 days to my 2nd datepicker whenever first one date changes.

**[Sample code here](http://jsbin.com/jurulejulo/edit?html,js,output)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were looking with 2 date pickers. You can make it as directive if you have the same case in many places(pages).

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() 
  {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() 
  {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions =
  {

    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.open1 = function() 
  {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };
   $scope.popup2 = {};

   $scope.open2 = function() 
  {
    $scope.popup2.opened = true;
  };
   
  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };

  
   $scope.$watch('dt',function(val,old)
   {
      $scope.opened = false;
      $scope.secondDate = new Date().setDate( new Date(val).getDate() + 7);

    });
  
   console.log($scope.dt);

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>


    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
<hr>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="secondDate" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>

    
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick solution. Use watcher on first date. Whenever first date changes add 7 days to second date.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {

    formatYear: 'yy',
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
    minDate: new Date(),
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.popup1.opened = true;
  };


  $scope.popup1 = {
    opened: false
  };
console.log($scope.dt);

$scope.secondDate = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+7)
$scope.$watch('dt', function(newVal, oldVal){
  var date = $scope.dt
  $scope.secondDate = new Date(date).setDate(new Date(date).getDate()+7)
})
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>
  <pre>Second date is: <em>{{secondDate | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>


    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>

      

    </div>

    
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```